# Recursive call with global variable in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have a tree and want to count sum of every left node and right node.
The tree layout is

```
 3  
/ \  
1  8  
  / \  
 6  15  
    / \  
   9   20  
      /  \  
     16  25  

public class BinarySearchTree {
    public int left_sum = 0;
    public int right_sum = 0;

    public int count_sum(Node x) {
        if (x == null) return 0;

        left_sum += count_sum(x.left);
        right_sum += count_sum(x.right);

        System.out.printf("left_sum = %d right_sum=%d\n", left_sum, right_sum);
        return x.data;
    }
}
```

But the right_sum is not correct. The value is just the node value.

```
left_sum = 0 right_sum=0  
left_sum = 1 right_sum=0  
left_sum = 7 right_sum=0  
left_sum = 16 right_sum=0  
left_sum = 32 right_sum=0  
left_sum = 32 right_sum=25  
left_sum = 32 right_sum=20  
left_sum = 32 right_sum=15  
left_sum = 32 right_sum=8
```

If I add one local variable 'int right' in count_sum() and modify a little as

```
public int count_sum(Node x) {
    int right;

    if (x == null) return 0;

    left_sum += count_sum(x.left);
    right = count_sum(x.right);
    right_sum += right;

    System.out.printf("left_sum = %d right_sum=%d\n", left_sum, right_sum);
    return x.data;
}

left_sum = 0 right_sum=0  
left_sum = 1 right_sum=0  
left_sum = 7 right_sum=0  
left_sum = 16 right_sum=0  
left_sum = 32 right_sum=0  
left_sum = 32 right_sum=25  
left_sum = 32 right_sum=45  
left_sum = 32 right_sum=60  
left_sum = 32 right_sum=68
```

The result is correct now. Why ?

Comment: How are you calling `count_sum()`? A little more code that shows what exactly you are running would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very hard to tell what's going on.  However, I can tell you why the two pieces of code behave differently.  When you say

```
right_sum += count_sum(x.right);
```

this is the same as

```
right_sum = right_sum + count_sum(x.right);
```

The code evaluates it this way:

1. Read the value of `right_sum`
2. Call `count_sum` (which changes the value of `right_sum`)
3. Add `right_sum` **using the value obtained in step 1** to the value returned by `count_sum`

By contrast:

```
right = count_sum(x.right);
right_sum += right;
```

which is the same as

```
right = count_sum(x.right);
right_sum = right_sum + right;
```

does things in a different order:

1. Call `count_sum` (which changes the value of `right_sum`)
2. Read the value of `right_sum`, **which is the new value of `right_sum` that has already been changed by `count_sum`**
3. Read the value of `right` (the result of the `count_sum` method)
4. Add the two

So you can see why the results would be different.

I think the moral here is simply to never use globals when writing a recursive method.  It is next to impossible to figure out what your code is doing, because you're using your globals and calling the method recursively in ways that change the globals.  (I'm very familiar with this from experience.  I previously worked on a compiler, and compilers by nature have a lot of trees and recursive code. 
 I've had tons of migraines trying to debug code where someone used a global in a recursive routine.)  So you can't tell what value you're working with and when.  The one exception I'd make is that you can have some kind of global collection (such as a `List` or `Set`) and write recursive methods that add to this collection, *but never read from it*.  That's pretty safe.

So how would you write this without using globals?  You have to think about how you'd write a recursive helper method that returns all the information needed.  So here, you might have a `countLeftAndRight` method that returns an object with two fields, where one is the sum of the left nodes and one is the sum of the right nodes.  You could declare an inner class like this:

```
private static class LeftAndRightSum {
    public int leftSum;
    public int rightSum;
    public LeftAndRightSum(int l, int r) { leftSum = l; rightSum = r; }
}
```

So `countLeftAndRight(t)` would return a pair {L, R} where L is the sum of the left nodes, R is the sum of the right nodes, and the value in the root isn't counted in either sum.  When working with recursion, it helps to have a *very precise* definition of what your recursive method does.  (It helps for every method in every program, actually, but it's especially important for recursion.)

So how would `countLeftAndRight` work?

1. Call `countLeftAndRight` recursively on the left subtree, returning {L1, R1}.
2. Call `countLeftAndRight` recursively on the right subtree, returning {L2, R2}.
3. Remember that `countLeftAndRight` doesn't add the value of the root in, which means you haven't yet added in the value of the left node (the root of the left subtree) or the right node.  So now your result will be {L1 + L2 + `left.value`, R1 + R2 + `right.value`}.

You'll need to make some obvious adjustments for null subtrees.

Doing it this way, without globals, will result in code that's much more understandable, and you'll have much more assurance that it's correct.

**MORE:** I thought of another moral: if you have a method that modifies a global, don't call that method in an expression that uses the same global somewhere else.  (So `left_sum += count_sum(x.left)` should be avoided, even in a non-recursive situation, because `count_sum` modifies `left_sum`.)  In Java, at least the behavior will be well-defined, but it can make the program difficult to understand.  In other languages like C++, this can have very nasty results, because the language rules allow compilers some freedom with regard to the order in which they evaluate things, which means that you could get different results with different compilers.  Very bad.  Avoid this at all costs.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation.